# Every time onActivityResult returning data as null in multi chain activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter

First of all, every answer of the related questions did not solve my problem, that's why I am creating a new question.

I have two apps. From the first app, I am calling intent for `ACTION_VIEW` with a URI with `onActivityResult`.

In the second app, I have set an intent filter for the same URI.

Now from Activity B, I am calling Activity C in App2 with `onActivityResult`.

From Activity C, I am calling Activity D with `onActivityResult`.

After some work in Activity D will set a result with some data in the bundle and set the result as OK.

Instead of getting this data in Activity C, I am getting intent in Activity B with data as null in the bundle.

And Activity B is sending the same response to Activity A of App1. Hence I am getting null data in App1 as well.

In Request,

```
App1 (Activity A) ---> App2 (Activity B) ---> Activity C ---> Activity D
```

In Response,

```
Expected : App1 (Activity A) <--- App2 (Activity B) <--- Activity C <--- Activity D

Actual : App1 (Activity A) <--- App2 (Activity B) <--- Activity D
with data as null.
```

Kindly help me to get data from Activity D of App2 to Activity A of App1.

**CODE:**

**App1 Activity A:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(deepLinkUrl));
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(chooser, 1);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (data.getExtras() != null) {
            Log.e("onActivityResult", "responseIntent.getExtras() " + 
                     data.getExtras());
        }
    }
}
```

**App2 Activity B:**

```
Constants.deeplinkUri = getIntent().getData();
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(Constants.deeplinkUri));
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (data.getExtras() != null) {
            Log.e("onActivityResult", "responseIntent.getExtras() " + 
                     data.getExtras());
        }
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**App2 Activity C:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PayActivity.class);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(Constants.deeplinkUri));
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (data.getExtras() != null) {
            Log.e("onActivityResult", "responseIntent.getExtras() " + 
                     data.getExtras());
        }
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**App2 Activity D:**

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result", msg);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Thanks in advance.
Anyone?

Comment: If you still need help, consider posting a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I just set up two apps to reproduce your situation, using as much of your code as possible, and everything works perfectly (so it's no problem if all the request codes are the same)

Comment: Can you share the project so that i can compare with my project.

Comment: Basically it's the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37187855/5015207). I only did not use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` and `startActivity()` with the `Intent` for (B -> C) and (C -> D) and copied your code instead. (Plus I wrote a small app to trigger my Activity A and used `onActivityResult()` in Activity A to pass everything back to the other app)  BTW if you're looking to "get data from Activity D of App2 to Activity A of App1", the approach in my answer might even be better for your use case because there it skips Activities C and B on the way back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've a problem in calling the `startActivityForResult`.

From your `ActivityA` you're launching `ActivityB` like this.

```
startActivityForResult(chooser, 1); // The request code is 1
```

From your `ActivityB` you're launching `ActivityC` with this.

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 100); // Request code 100
```

And from `ActivityC` you're launching `ActivityD` with the same request code which is 100.

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);  // Same request code 100
```

So when your `ActivityD` is setting some results and passes the result intent to the calling `Activity` it immediately passes the result with `super` call to its parent. In your case, it immediately passes the result to `ActivityB` and there's a handler in `ActivityB` to handle the request code `100` too which gets the null value.

So you might try setting different request code from each of your `Activity` here to avoid this situation.

From your `ActivityB` launch `ActivityC` like this.

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);  // Request code 100
```

And from `ActivityC` launch `ActivityD` like this

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 101);  // Request code 101
```

Now add the handler in `ActivityC` to handle the result with request code `101` in `ActivityC`.

Hope that will solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry not working :( Still getting the same null response in ActivityB

Comment: It should. Now I'm confused about what's wrong in here. You had the annotation `@Override` on the function `onActivityResult` right?

Comment: Yes in every activity

Comment: Glad to know that helped!