# How do I finish activities in a library and return to the parent application?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm writing a library that starts a flow of activities when the user does some action. If back is never pressed, the flow should be:

- Application using library detects some action on ParentAppScreen1 >
- LibraryActivity1: user taps next >
- LibraryActivity2: user taps send >
- user is returned to ParentAppScreen1

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
          // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
          case android.R.id.home:
              this.finish();
              return true;

          case R.id.action_send:
              sendReport();

              // TODO go back to where the user started in parent app
      }

      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

  }
  ```

Is there any kind of standard practice for this? I'm not finding much when browsing documentation, and I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: If you're okay with the users *always* returning to where they started in the parent app then `startActivityForResult()` could do the job. There is a flag by which one can concatenate several Activities before returning the result (if any). Once upon a time I posted an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37187855/5015207), maybe it's helpful.

Comment: Hmmm... I that would cause any back buttons to essentially quit the flow as well. I'll look into a workaround.

Comment: As long as they are all in the same task, you could just call `finishAffinity()` on the current Activity: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity()

Comment: @jch000 finishAffinity() works for my purposes, thanks!