# Open Android App activity with intent, finish login workflow, then return result to initiator activity

Tags: android, android-intent

Here's the setup:

2 Apps.

I) 1st App `SomeActivity` initiates intent to another app's activity (i.e. `LoginActivity`) (DONE)

II) 2nd App receives this intent and starts login process: `LoginActivity`->`EnterUsernameActivity`->`EnterPasswordActivity`

III)How to kill `EnterPasswordActivity` and return user **id/name** to `SomeActivity` which is in the 1st App?

If There was only 1 Activity for login, it would be simple by creating a returningIntent and just `setResult()` + `finish()`.

Thanks

Comment: Once upon a time I posted a detailed example on how to use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT in such cases - hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37187855/5015207) helps :)

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll try that out :)